# Cast Session to object

Tags: c#, session, telerik

I am assigning into a session a RadTreeNode object (i checked from debugger that the session is not null). And then i am trying to cast it back to RadTreeNode object with the following code.

```
 RadTreeNode node = new RadTreeNode();
      node =  (RadTreeNode)Session["nextNode"] as RadTreeNode;
```

But the node variable still null. Any suggestions ?

Comment: It probably means that it is not in the session. Is your write correct? Your cast is funky btw.

Comment: What is the type of `Session["nextNode"]` *immediately* before these two statements?

Comment: It has a radTreeNode inside!. I checked it. I have in another method a statement Session["nextNode"] = newRadTreeNode which is type RadTreeNode

Comment: You are using two forms of casting (ObjectType) and As ObjectType.  You should only use the As ObjectType for a reference type like this.  Your code should say node = Session["nextNode"] as RadTreeNode.  Also, you really should avoid using Session.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a good chance that Session["nextNode"] is null, as eluded to by @Richard in his comment.

The "as" cast `as RadTreeNode` will yield a null value if the source object does not convert to the target type.  The prefix cast `(RadTreeNode)` targets a reference type and will not throw an exception when the `as RadTreeNode` cast fails.

You're casting a null value to RadTreeNode and you're getting what you're supposed to... a null reference of RadTreeNode.

Session is generally bad and should be avoided whenever at all possible.  My guess is you're expecting Session to behave one way and its not.

For example, is `RadTreeNode` serializable?  It's been a while so I don't remember how Session handles serializing/deserializing objects but my guess is it will eat any exceptions related to serialization.  Admittedly a guess.